# How to match same values in three columns and display a value of 3rd column into new column using Excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a excel sheet where I need to match the values of Columns "A","B","C" and return a duplicate value of Column "C" as one value into Column "D" . The similar columns are Team, Month, Value. The fourth column is called "Actual Value" here the matching and repeated value should appear based on Column A.

Excel table:
[image]

The formula I tried :

=IF(A3=B3;C:C;"C3")

but this is not giving the Output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in D3 and copy down:

```
=IF(OR(A3<>A2,B3<>B2),C3,"")
```

This assumes your data is sorted on A then B as your example shows.

It test whether the data changes from the line above.  If true then it returns the value.  If false it returns an empty string.

[image]

Comment: Great! Works perfect :) I was trying from long time for this formula.Thanks alot.